# Check a checkbox that has a particular ID value

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have records being retrieved from a database using Jquery which value and checkboxes are appended on a div,
I currently want the record which ID is = 5 in the database to be checked when this records are being retrieved.
Please any help

Below is the code that retrieves the records and append each record in a div.

```js
function loadState(xxxxxxTypeDDL) {
  if ($(xxxxxxTypeDDL).val() == "") {
    clearState(xxxxxxTypeDDL);
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: "/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      global: false,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 30000,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#ajax-loading-placeholder").html('<img src="/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="...Loading" /> ...Loading').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          width: 32,
          height: 60,
          modal: true,
          resizable: false
        }).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
        // alert("Weldone Dude");
        $("#ajax-loading-placeholder").dialog('open');
        clearState(xxxxxxTypeDDL);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-loading-placeholder').dialog('destroy').html('');
        var htmlToInsert = "";
        if (data == null) {
          $("<div></div>").text("No State found matching your selection criteria").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Select Required State',
            buttons: {
              "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog('destroy').html('');
              }
            }
          }).dialog("open");
          clearState(xxxxxxTypeDDL);
          $(xxxxxxTypeDDL).val("");
          $("#selected-state").hide();
          return;
        }
        $(data.State).each(function() {
          var input = "<div style='margin-bottom:5px' class='retrieved-state-list'><input type='checkbox' id='";
          input += "RetrievedState' value='";
          input += this.ID;

          if ($.inArray(this.ID.toString(), data.SelectedState) > -1) {
            input += "' checked='checked";
          }

          input += "' </input><span style='display:none'>" + this.Name + "</span>";
          input += "<span>" + this.Description + "</span></div>"
          htmlToInsert += input;
        });
```

Comment: I think because you are not forming your input tag properly here. You are not closing '>' the input after checked

Answer (score 3):

For every row in your display info element,

```
<div data-id="<IDs>" class="display:none"></div>
```

In js, get this value via `.attr()` link http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
JQuery.each($('div[data-id]'), function(i, val) {
   if (val.attr('data-id') == "5") {
      // Do some stuff here
   }
})
```

Comment: If you have `data-` attributes, better to use $("..").data(..)` than `.attr` as it will by more efficient and also convert to the correct type, eg `<div data-id="5">` `$("div").data("id") === 5` but `$("div").attr("data-id") === "5"`

Comment: It throws an exception of val.attr is not a function

Comment: Sorry there mistake span[data-id] shoud change to div or the css selector much that area